# React.js - Flow.js works, but does not check the type of properties

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

#### Problem:

`yarn flow` command works correctly, detects whether `Props` contains a specific property, but does not check the property type.

#### Configuration:

React.js (create-react-app) + Flow.js

#### Example:

```
<SomeComponent some={'Some text'} />

...

type Props = {
  some: boolean // some wrong type
};

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.some}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Result:

1. If I do not declare the `some` field in `Props`, the `yarn flow` command will return: *Cannot get this.props.some because property some is missing in Props*... **This is ok!**
2. But... `yarn flow` command does not react to the props type. Although the variable contains `string` and the type is set to`boolean`, I get the message: *No errors!*

#### Question:

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you provide us more info on your setup, or better, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have it working: `...because string [1] is incompatible with boolean [2] in property \`some\``

Comment: here is an example https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciiOAnukqgACo3RkAvKADeoEk0oAuUACNYsaNQB2oAL68a0UmQDCTTNsra8lAB45rAEzJVaOAHTmMsKzYA8YrASAHyyiKCg7NpOlFgAFACU4ZGR7DgArli6-iToRNohMjgAFsgkHujiFQqolHr+wHkFITyRBgaI-t6W1ni1lJIARACMAEwAzEOgwCFAA